# How do you hang a thread in Java in one line?

Tags: java, multithreading

By one line I mean at most 100 chars per line.

(I basically need this to keep the program alive. The main thread registers callback listeners that are run in separate threads. I just need the main one to hang forever and let the other threads do their work)

Comment: why not leave the "main thread" just terminate? If there are non-daemon threads running, the VM will not terminate them.

Comment: I actually didn't want to use 100% CPU in the hanging thread.

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger - I actually don't have access to the other threads. They're hidden behind the library I use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few things you could do that would be better than hanging the initial thread forever:

1. Use [`otherThread.join()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).  This will cause the current thread you are running in to sleep until the other thread has finished executing.
2. As @nanda suggests, use [ExcecutorService.shutdown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to wait until a pool of threads has finished.
3. Use [`otherThread.setDaemon(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) and simply let your initial thread exit.  This will set your new threads as user threads.  Java will not shut down until the only threads running are daemon threads.

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong but using join() means that there is only two threads right? main program and listener. Whereas the OP wants listeners.

Comment: @nanda, the assumption (probably correct) is that the OP wants listeners so he can be notified when threads have finished executing whilst the main thread is in something like a `sleep()` loop waiting for this to happen.  The extra callback work is not necessary if you use any of the answers given.

Comment: Just loop over your threads and call join() for each one.  Once one finishes the loop will join the next one.  When your loop exits you can be sure that the last thread has exited.

Answer (score 14):

```
synchronized(this) {
    while (true) {
        this.wait();
    }
}
```

(thanks to Carlos Heuberger. Exception handling omitted in the above code)

This will make the current thread wait on the monitor of the current class until someone calls `notify()`, or forever.

Comment: +1 - but beware of spurious wake-ups: you need a forever loop around the wait since it can spuriously (that is, for no reason) return. Catching InterruptedException also needed... it's a bigger one-liner, but probably the best (correct) solution

Comment: I don't like this answer simply on the basis that you aren't actually waiting for anything. (still not down-voting though)

Comment: @Tim Bender - I agree. I answered instinctively to "how to _hang_ a thread". :)

Comment: Would it be better to wait on a dummy `Object` instance, instead of `this`?

Answer (score 6):

`Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);`

Ok, so it isn't forever, but talk about a really long time :)

Comment: wrapped this in while(true), loving it.

Comment: Wrapping it in while is redundant for all practical purposes as the thread will sleep for 292471208.7 years! Practically that's forever...

Comment: I think there is an exceptional condition which would require the while wrapping to ignore.

Answer (score 5):

Use executor. By using method shutdown() you'll force the executor to wait until all threads are finished.

Comment: I agree, you should use the new concurrent package: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: then the main porgram will not 'hang' forever

Comment: I bet the meaning of 'forever' that OP means is that the main program wait until all threads are finished. I might be wrong :)

Comment: I think you're wrong. It sounds like the OP wants to create a service that listens for messages and does something literally forever. An exit condition probably isn't even in the design.

Answer (score 5):

With a [CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) you can wait untill the count down reached 0, if you make sure it never counts down, maybe only when it needs to end. (This also result in 0% cpu, the opposite of loops that will run forever, and with join() your app will still finish when all other threads finished, The option of the executor is better, but will also end when all executed task have finished)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [thread.join](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) to wait for all of the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is a one-liner, in that you only have to add one extra line.  (You do have to add `synchronized` and `throws InterruptedException` to your `main` declaration though.)  Also, it does not need access to, or even knowledge of the threads in the library you are using.

```
public static synchronized void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
  ...
  YourMainClass.class.wait();  // wait forever
}
```

It assumes you will never call `notify` on your main class and that you want to exit if you get an `InterruptedException`.  (You can add a `while (true) { ... }` around the `wait` line if you really want to guard against that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    t.setDaemon(false);
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while(true) { Thread.sleep(1000); }

Comment: It is kind of wasteful and unintuitive to let the thread wake up every second just to put it to sleep again. See Tim Benders reply for a better approach using `Thead.sleep(long)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(;;);
```

But it's very unlikely that hanging the thread is what you want.  Instead, you should consider options like joining on the other threads.

Comment: @rsp, true.  This is how to hang the thread, but it's very unlikely the OP actually wants to do that.