# Keylistener for Ctrl+C from another program

Tags: java, javafx, clipboard, keylistener

I want to automatically put the contents into a textArea when a text in notepad is copied via <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. I'm wondering of how to listen to the Keys of notepad. Is it possible to listen to Keys of notepad or any other program?

Comment: Listen to the clipboard instead. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14226064/2855515

Comment: Listening to `Ctrl+C` globally is possible. It's called a keylogger and it's definitely nothing you want to implement in your java-application. As @brian already pointed out, the better approach is to listen for the system-clipboard instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a JavaFX version of the clipboard listeners referenced in other answers and comments:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SystemClipboardWatcher extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea clipboardView = new TextArea();

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

            Clipboard systemClipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();

            @Override
            public void handle(long timestamp) {
                String content = systemClipboard.getString();
                // do anything you need with this, e.g.:
                clipboardView.setText(content);
            }
        };

        timer.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(clipboardView, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get all keyevents of all application in java.

So you have 2 possible solutions.

1. You only get the changes of the clipboard, with a clipboard-listener. [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440177/why-do-clipboard-listener-use-more-cpu-usage)
2. Use of JNA, JNI, jintellitype, ... to listen to the system-keyevents [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174119/global-keylistener-using-jna)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but a very bad coding practice. If you still want to do it: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook.
A way better idea would be to watch for changes in the clipboard.