# How to Keep Listener Thread Alive

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class which is a listener for incoming messages and should be alive forever (So that it can listen for incoming messages) until i explicitly disconnect the connection for it. I have declared the thread as setDaemon(false) but it terminates with the calling methods termination.

Please tell me how to keep that thread alive and also please throw some light on how to implement the Spring TaskExecutor to achieve same.

Thanks in advance.
it is a listener it gets notified when someone sends message... so how do i keep it running ?

**The Listener Class**

```
public class MyListnerImpl implements Listener {
    private final connectionImpl con;   

    public MyListnerImpl(ConnectionImpl con) {
    if (con.isAuthenticated() && con.isConnected()) {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Initializing XmppListner:");
        }
        this.itsCon = con;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.setDaemon(false);
        t1.start();
    }
    }

    public final void listnerInterfaceMethod(final Chat chat, final Message message) {
        System.out.println("Message" + message);
    }

    public final void run() {
    itsCon.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
        public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, final boolean createdLocally) {
            if (!createdLocally) {
                chat.addMessageListener(itsFbml);
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Calling class simply creates its object and thread gets started by the Listeners constructor.

I want to keep this thread created run until i interrupt it.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you hang a thread in Java in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203139/how-do-you-hang-a-thread-in-java-in-one-line)

Comment: I have posted the thread, gentleman please tell me what you guys usually do to keep listener running ?

Comment: I would think that the listener should stay registered forever unless the `ChatManager` is removing the listener for some reason.  You should not need to do the register in a background thread and there is no reason to keep that thread running.  As Peter points out, your listener code will be called from a different thread.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but the thread here is useless, as others said you can get rid of it and seek your problem elsewhere.

Comment: Ok Gray so listener calls from somewhere else.
@Flavio Try to understand, this piece of code is not useless, it gets notified in case of any event...  the question is simple,it must be alive to listen to that notification, but this code also terminates with main method. if any of you wise people can help me to do that, i would be greatfull.
How can we instantiate a listener so that i keeps listening for events ??

Comment: I did not say the code is useless; I'm saying that it is useless to run it into a separate thread. You can run the code in the main thread, you don't need another thread here. Just put a `while(true) sleep(1000);` in your main thread, if that's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you could do that would be better than hanging the initial thread forever:

Use `otherThread.join()`. This will cause the current thread you are running in to sleep until the other thread has finished executing.
As @nanda suggests, use `ExcecutorService.shutdown()` to wait until a pool of threads has finished.
Use `otherThread.setDaemon(false)` and simply let your initial thread exit. This will set your new threads as user threads. Java will not shut down until the only threads running are daemon threads.

```
synchronized(this) {
    while (true) {
        this.wait();
    }
}
```

This will make the current thread wait on the monitor of the current class until someone calls `notify()`, or forever.

copied from [How do you hang a thread in Java in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203139/how-do-you-hang-a-thread-in-java-in-one-line)

Comment: How were you able to answer this 6 _seconds_ after the question was posted?

Comment: @Gray it doesnt take long to copy paste!

Comment: read the last line and it took 6 minute to find the correct answer for this question and also mention that from where i got this answer

Comment: Boss you guys try to understand, i have a non daemon thread that vanishes !!

Answer (score 1):

A thread says alive until `run()` returns (or throw an error/exception)  If you want to keep it alive, use a loop, don't return and catch any error/exception.

Comment: Hello peter, it is a listener it gets notified when someone sends message... so how do i keep it running ? I have declared it as non daemon thread but terminates with caller threads termination.  How do you implement such kind of thing ?

Comment: It is not clear if you control the thread or not.  Whether it is a deamon or not only matters in preventing the program from exiting.  If you control the thread, you need to change your code.  If the thread is created by a library, you need to understand how the library works.

Comment: BTW The thread you started doesn't appear to do anything.  You could remove it and it will do the same thing. It is not the thread the listener will can called on.

Comment: thanks for replying peter, This code basically gets notified when a message arrives... So this must alive when some one looks for it... So how to keep it alive any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the problems that time, 
So this case was not of multi threading , had just a single thread which needed to run for ever, 
So Inserted

```
public final void run() {
while(true)
{
//Run Method Logic...
}
}
```

And instantiated it from a spring bean.
I was also looking at more fancy things for this single threaded scenario like awaitTermination(); or something like that.